# Swift UITextField inside TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I am using a table view and have a UITextField inside it, but this text field don't detect the click on the cell. How I can fix this?

Comment: can you share that screen ?

Comment: the screen with the UITextView

Answer (score 0):

subclass the uitextfield, in prepareforreuse, set the delegate to nil, in the cellforrowatindexpath in the uitableview/datasource delegate, set the the textfield delegate to self, then implement the tableview methods there. to determine which textfield is clicked, index at point functions for tableview in the UITableView header, once you find that point, convert it to NSIndexPath. use that indexpath to find the array value where you store the textfield text values, update that value, then reload the row or the entire tableview and viola, you have your textfield population and working correctly,

lastly, show your code, this is very difficult to answer without showing your code